Ping works on Ubuntu 24.04 but not on Ubuntu 18.04 with the same setup
I have a simple setup where two hosts H1 and H2 are connected to an L2 switch.
I am setting up a vxlan overlay network on each of the hosts by running the following commands on each host (replace x in 192.168.100.x with 1, and 2 respectively):
   sudo ip link add if-backbone type vxlan id 1000 dev eth0 group 239.255.1.1 dstport 4789
   sudo ip address add 192.168.100.x/24 dev if-backbone
   sudo ip link set dev if-backbone up

then I am adding another IP address on H1's if-backbone interface:
   ip address add 192.168.10.1/24 dev if-backbone

then I am trying to ping the 192.168.10.1 address from H2
   ping -I if-backbone 192.168.10.1

H1 is running ubuntu 24.04
when H2 is an Nvidia Jetson running ubuntu 18.04 the ping is not received at H2 and the packet are 100% lost, but when running Wireshark capture on H2, I can see the ARP and the ICMP request/reply messages correctly.
When H2 is an RPi5 running ubuntu 24.04 the ping works correctly for 100% of the packets
what could be causing this behavior ?

FYI, the recommended Ubuntu release for Nvidia Jetson is 22.04, currently. Ubuntu 18.04 is out of standard support.
